# Import excel to SQL via python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database

I'm a basic user of python pandas, I've tried to create this connection below but I'm having this error. Im just trying to import xlsx file to sql server.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\ehan\\Desktop\\Python Scripts\\New folder\\sample.xlsx')
engine=create_engine('mssql://EMEA\ehan@/peter')
df.to_sql=('test', con==engine)
NameError: name 'con' is not defined
```

Comment: you have a typo `df.to_sql=('test', con=engine)`

Comment: you should  define your table and relevant schema. `df.to_sql(name='test',schema='stg', con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)`

Comment: but df.to_sql=('test', con=engine) gives me sytax error thats why I've changed it to double ==

Comment: df.to_sql=('test', con==engine) is this supposed to define my table name 'test' ?